# Installing Programs, ie Java 8 jdk

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

I am trying to migrate from Windows to Linux. Why is so difficult for beginners to install programs to a linux computer. Starting to miss the self extracting executable programs in Windows.
I have spend hours trying to load Java8 JDK to begin to develop some programs.
Can anyone give me some very simple help to install Java 8jdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can install OpenJDK 8 with these packages. Simply download them, open them in the Ubuntu Software Center, and click install.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/openjdk-8-jre_8u40~b09-1_amd64.deb
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/openjdk-8-jdk_8u40~b09-1_amd64.deb

You can view all available packages on OpenJDK's Launchpad page.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use the built-in programs (packages) to install tested verified working programs, using the Software Center, or Synaptic, or apt (apt-get, apt-cache...) in the terminal.

To make sure you can install all the programs you want, check the repositories in the Software Sources (somewhere in the dashboard/menus in Ubuntu unity?) to include the universe, multiverse, programs (different categories of programs, basically separated by license restrictions I think) maybe even backport or romeo (unstable) and could add extra repos like `archive.getdeb.net` and there are some other outside, possibly less tested PPAs for various programs or places. And update the list of available packages after that, Software Sources should have an update, or terminal `sudo apt-get update`

Then run the Software Center, or Synaptic, or `apt-cache search ...` to find & install stuff.

You can still download & install any available programs you want from any random website, but it could be untested, may not work, may break stuff, may be a virus/trojan, etc, just like windows! For example mozilla/firefox .tar.gz files are available to extract and run, but I trust them more than a random "Creepy Bob's cool mystery program website - RUN ME!"

The first time I ran Ubuntu I didn't have a clue how to install programs, there really should be a "Quick Start for absolute beginners" on how to do basics like this.